# How to use departmentNumber attiribute in LDAP

Tags: ldap

I'm looking for a way to use departmentNumber attribute in LDAP. In Active Directory user class has the attribute of department so I can put the department name into it, but inetOrgPerson has only the departmentNumber attribute and it's just a number.

If I want to retrieve the department name from users, how do I resolve the departmentNumber to the department name? I guess there may be a lot of ways to do it, but I want to know the general way of doing it in LDAP.

Comment: [It can be numeric or alphanumeric](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2798). If you have an AD user entry you have `deparrmentName`: if you have an `inetOrgPerson` you have `departmentNumber`; but am an entry can't be both at the same time. Unclear what you're asking,

Comment: Thank you for your comment and sorry for my unclear question. I'm new at Redhat LDAP and  I need to compare Redhat LDAP and Active Directory. If I use Active Directory I can put a department name on the department attribute in Active directory but If I use Redhat, it is available only departmentNumber and couldn't  find the department attribute. I appreciate if you can tell me how to use departmentNumber to get department name or how to express user's department generally with Redhat LDAP. Thanks O.M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite its name attribute *departmentNumber* as defined in [RFC 2798](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2798#section-2.2) can contain any Unicode character entities.

Assuming that you're talking about adding organizational information to person / user entries my usual recommendation is:

- store the short department name or number into attribute *departmentNumber* and
- store the matching longer descriptive department name into attribute *ou* (as defined in [RFC 4519](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4519#section-2.20))